# Interactive charts/graphs in PDF file

Tags: pdf, air

I want to add an interactive graph/chart in pdf file with a slider or links. So whenever user click on a link or change the value of slider then graph regenerate according to this. There is no dynamic data (no need to get data from database or xml etc).

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How many possible distinct chart versions could you end up displaying?  If not too many, you could render all possible charts at the same position in the document but on separate layers and [use Javascript to hide or show](http://www.planetpdf.com/developer/article.asp?ContentID=focus_on_pdf_layers_ocg_) all but one chart layer.